# to use salt-source bean, which domain do I need to implement?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement a salt source as part of my security in Spring security 3. I want to salt the username, but in order to use this as shown below, which domain do I need to implement in order to take advantage of spring security's default implementations???

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256">
            <salt-source user-property="username" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess with domain you're referring to the Security Namespace. The location of the Spring Security Namespace Configuration is: http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd (don't specify the version to resolve against the latest one). Have a look at the documentation: [Spring Security Namespace Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html)

Comment: no, i am referring to a class with getters/setters. which class do i need to implement?

Comment: If you want to create your own, instead of using Spring's default one,  you have to implement the `org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.SaltSource` interface. But this is an *interface*, not a *domain*.